reinstantiate/instantiate StateFlow at runtime with argument passed by ui
i'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to instantiate a stateflow with an argument passed by the ui to the viewModel.I've tried many solutions but without success.
Here's the situation.

this is the viewmodel


data class MealsCategoriesUiState(
    val mealsCategories: List<MealCategory> = listOf()
)

data class MealDetailUiState(
    val mealDetailState: Meal
)

data class MealsUiState(
    val meals: List<Meal> = listOf()
)

class MealsViewModel(
    private val mealsCategoriesRepository: IMealsCategoriesRepository,
    private val mealsRepository: IMealsRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

    val mealsCategoriesUiState: StateFlow<MealsCategoriesUiState> = mealsCategoriesRepository
                                                                        .getAllLocalMealsCategories()
                                                                        .map { MealsCategoriesUiState(it) }
                                                                        .stateIn(
                                                                            scope = viewModelScope,
                                                                            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000L),
                                                                            initialValue = MealsCategoriesUiState()
                                                                        )

    val mealsUiState: StateFlow<MealsUiState> = mealsRepository
        // how do i get by the ui the category string???
        .getAllMealsByCategory()
        .map { MealsUiState(it) }
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000L),
            initialValue = MealsUiState()
        )

    val mealsDetailUiState: StateFlow<MealDetailUiState> = mealsRepository
        // how do i get by the ui the id string???
        .getMealById()
        .map { MealDetailUiState(it) }
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000L),
            initialValue = MealDetailUiState()
        )

// this is launched at startup by categoryscreen
    fun refreshDb() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                Log.d("errorToast", "Wifi detected, refresh of local db")
                val allRemoteCategoryMeals: List<MealCategory> = mealsCategoriesRepository.getAllRemoteCategories()
                val allRemoteMeals: List<Meal> = mealsRepository.getAllRemoteMeals()
                mealsCategoriesRepository.insertMealsCategoriesList(allRemoteCategoryMeals)
                mealsRepository.insertMealsList(allRemoteMeals)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.d("errorToast", "IO error")
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                Log.d("errorToast", "Network error")
            }
        }
    }
}

this is categoryscreen

@Composable
fun CategoriesScreen(
    userName: String = "test",
    viewModel: MealsViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory),
    navController : NavController,
    modifier :  Modifier = Modifier
) {
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        viewModel.refreshDb()
    }

    var insertedMeal by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val mealsCategoriesUiState by viewModel.mealsCategoriesUiState.collectAsState()

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        // TODO estrai come stringa per localizzazione
        Text(text = stringResource(R.string.benvenuto, userName), fontSize = 30.sp, modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 10.dp))
        Row() {
            TextField(
                value = insertedMeal,
                onValueChange = { insertedMeal = it; Log.d("mealInput", insertedMeal) },
                label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.cerca_piatto)) },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 10.dp)
            )
        }
        CategoriesGrid(categoriesList = mealsCategoriesUiState.mealsCategories, navController)
    }
}


@Composable
fun CategoryCard(
    category: MealCategory,
    navController: NavController
) {
    ElevatedCard(
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
            defaultElevation = 6.dp
        ),
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate(ChefMasterScreens.Meals.name + "/" + category.strCategory)
            // set in viewModel observable category to category, in viewmodel assign it to flow
                  },
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
        modifier = Modifier.height(210.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(category.strCategory)
        }
        Box{
            AsyncImage(
                model = category.strCategoryThumb,
                contentDescription = "",
                error = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_broken_image),
                placeholder = painterResource(R.drawable.loading_img),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CategoriesGrid(
    categoriesList: List<MealCategory>,
    navController: NavController
) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
        items(categoriesList, key = { category -> category.idCategory }) {
                category ->
            CategoryCard(
                category = category,
                navController = navController
            )
        }
    }
}

this is the mealsScreen
@Composable
fun MealsScreen(
    categoryName: String,
    viewModel: MealsViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory),
    navController: NavController,
    modifier :  Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var insertedMeal by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val mealsUiState by viewModel.mealsUiState.collectAsState()

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text(text = categoryName, fontSize = 30.sp, modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 10.dp))
        Row() {
            TextField(
                value = insertedMeal,
                onValueChange = { insertedMeal = it; Log.d("mealInput", insertedMeal) },
                label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.cerca_piatto)) },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 10.dp)
            )
        }
        MealsGrid(
            mealsList = mealsUiState.meals,
            navController = navController
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun MealsGrid(
    mealsList: List<Meal>,
    navController: NavController
) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
        // TODO gestisci caso in cui non ci sono elementi in memoria
        items(mealsList, key = { meal -> meal.idMeal }) {
                meal ->
            MealsCard(
                meal = meal,
                onClickCallback = { navController.navigate("Detail" + "/" + meal.idMeal) }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MealsCard(
    meal: Meal,
    onClickCallback: () -> Unit
) {
    ElevatedCard(
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
            defaultElevation = 6.dp
        ),
        onClick = onClickCallback,
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
        modifier = Modifier.height(210.dp)
    ) {
        Column {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.width(120.dp)){
                    Text(meal.strMeal)
                }
                Box(modifier = Modifier.width(20.dp)) {
                    IconButton(onClick = { /* do something */ }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.FavoriteBorder,
                            contentDescription = ""
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            Box{
                AsyncImage(
                    model = meal.strMealThumb,
                    contentDescription = "",
                    error = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_broken_image),
                    placeholder = painterResource(R.drawable.loading_img),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                )
            }
        }

    }
}

this is the navigation
@Composable
fun ChefMasterAppNavigation(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(
        modifier = modifier,
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = ChefMasterScreens.Categories.name
    ) {
        // schermata categories
        composable(route = ChefMasterScreens.Categories.name) {
            CategoriesScreen(navController = navController)
        }

        // schermata meals di una categoria
        composable(
            route = ChefMasterScreens.Meals.name + "/{category}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("category") {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    nullable = false
                }
            )
        ) {
            entry ->
            entry.arguments?.getString("category")?.let { MealsScreen(
                                                                categoryName = it,
                                                                navController = navController
                                                            ) }
        }

        // schermata dettagli meal selected
        composable(
            route = ChefMasterScreens.Detail.name + "/{mealId}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("mealId") {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    defaultValue = "12345"
                    nullable = false
                }
            )
        ) {
                entry ->
            entry.arguments?.getString("mealId")?.let { MealDetail(mealId = it) }
        }

        // schermata preferiti
        composable(route = ChefMasterScreens.Favorites.name) {

        }

        // schermata login registrazione
        composable(route = ChefMasterScreens.LoginRegister.name) {
            LoginRegisterScreen()
        }
    }
}

i tried making using an internal state in the viewmodel but without success, also i believed it was not best practice

It sounds like the category string's value should itself be represented as a flow, probably a StateFlow, and that you should be using Flow.combine or some similar mechanism to bring its value into the logic chain.
